# NS2-tcl - divide the field into squares?

Tags: tcl, area, ns2, divide

I am working on ns2.35-ubuntu10.04. I want to divide the sensor field into 9 squares of equal size by using TCL script. This is my first attempt but there is no result. (The steps of division is delimited by the star mark and [attachment picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOkYU.png).)

```
# Define options
set val(chan)    Channel/WirelessChannel     ;  # channel type   
set val(prop)    Propagation/TwoRayGround    ;  # radio-propagation model  
set val(netif)   Phy/WirelessPhy             ;  # network interface type  
set val(mac)     Mac/802_11                  ;  # MAC type   
set val(ifq)     Queue/DropTail/PriQueue     ;  # interface queue type  
set val(ll)      LL                          ;  # link layer type  
set val(ant)     Antenna/OmniAntenna         ; # antenna model  
set val(ifqlen)  50                          ;  # max packet in ifq  
set val(rp)      AODV                       ;  # routing protocol  
set val(x)       900                         ;  # X dimension of topography  
set val(y)       900                         ;  # Y dimension of topography   
set val(stop)    10                          ;  # time of simulation end  
set val(Y)        0;  
set val(X)        0;   
set val(nn)      30 ;  


#Creating simulation:  
set ns [new Simulator]  

#Creating nam and trace file:  
set tracefd [open k.tr w]  
set namtrace [open k.nam w]     
$ns trace-all $tracefd  
$ns namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $val(x) $val(y)  

# set up topography object   
set topo [new Topography]    
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)    
set god_ [create-god $val(nn)]   

# configure the nodes 
$ns node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \  
                -llType $val(ll) \  
                -macType $val(mac) \  
                -ifqType $val(ifq) \  
                -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \  
                -antType $val(ant) \  
                -propType $val(prop) \  
                -phyType $val(netif) \  
                -channelType $val(chan) \  
                -topoInstance $topo \  
                -agentTrace ON \  
                -routerTrace ON \  
                -macTrace OFF \  

############ BEGIN ############
set $val(X)  [expr $val(x)/300]  
set $val(Y)  [expr $val(y)/300]  
for {set i 0} {$i<=$val(X)} {incr i}   
{  
for {set j 0} {$j<=$val(Y)}  {incr i}  
{  
for {set b 0} {$b < $val(nn) } { incr b }   
 {
     set node($b) [$ns node]
}  
}  
}
############ END ############

#stop procedure..   

proc stop {}   {
    global ns tracefd namtrace  
    $ns flush-trace  
    close $tracefd  
    close $namtrace  
    exec nam k.nam &  
 }

$ns at $val(stop) "stop"  

$ns run
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really a “fix my code for me” when it is thoroughly broken in many ways. It's just not focussed enough to be a sensible Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at just the code you highlighted:

```
set $val(X)  [expr $val(x)/300]  
set $val(Y)  [expr $val(y)/300]  
for {set i 0} {$i<=$val(X)} {incr i}   
{  
for {set j 0} {$j<=$val(Y)}  {incr i}  
{  
for {set b 0} {$b < $val(nn) } { incr b }   
 {
     set node($b) [$ns node]
}  
}  
}
```

The main problem is that you've put open braces on lines of their own. Don't do that in Tcl; the language *enormously* prefers One True Brace style (because newlines are significant, being command terminators).  If we change to this (the indentation is just for clarity):

```
set $val(X) [expr $val(x)/300]
set $val(Y) [expr $val(y)/300]
for {set i 0} {$i<=$val(X)} {incr i} {
    for {set j 0} {$j<=$val(Y)} {incr i} {
        for {set b 0} {$b < $val(nn)} {incr b} {
            set node($b) [$ns node]
        }
    }
}
```

Then the code will run. It will probably not produce quite what you expect though, since you're not using either the `i` or the `j` value in the innermost loop. When you make a node, you need to somehow tell it where it is in the grid.

Also, you're using three nested loops, so you're (probably) making a 3D grid. Is this what you intend? (As you're also just saving information about one dimension in the key, that probably means you're using just one tiny fraction of that grid and completely losing track of the other undifferentiated nodes.)

Comment: the first two loops are to divide the field into grid, the third is used to create 30 node so i use as a loop instead of re-write the creation step.

Comment: there in no error after running the code but there is no result to show